# Regularity requirements for Sard's Theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, critical-point-theory

The most common formulation of Sard's Theorem is that for $f\in C^{n-m+1}(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$ with $n\ge m$, the set $f(C_f)$ has Lebesgue measure 0, where $C_f=\{x, df(x)=0\}$.

**Question.** Is it possible to weaken the assumption (and keep the conclusion) by assuming only
$f\in C^{n-m}(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$, $f$ is $n-m+1$ times differentiable with a locally bounded $n-m+1$ derivative?

Answer (score 5):

According to *Bates, S. M. (1993). Toward a precise smoothness hypothesis in Sard’s theorem. Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, 117(1), 279-283,* the answer is **yes**:

- By Theorem 1 in that paper, it is sufficient that $(n-m)$-th
  derivative is Lipschitz.
- By Theorem 3, there are counterexamples with $\alpha$-Hölder $(n-m)$-th derivative for every $\alpha<1$.